# How can I check for a specific role in a different guild and make it a boolean?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const Command = require("../../Ana/Command")
const config = require("../../config.json")
const prefix = config.prefix;

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "team",
    aliases: ["tm"],
    description: "Gives you your desired team.",
    category: "Gamemaster",

    run: async (bot, message, args, client, Discord) => {
        await message.reply("Please wait!").then(async msg => {
            var command = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ")[0],
                topic = message.content.split(" ")[1];
            const isTRO = message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === '948567643194003476') //Checks if you have a role in a different server, the bot is invited in that specific server
            switch (command) {
                case "team":
                    if (!topic) return message.channel.send('no team selected.... are you kid??');
                    if (topic === "TRO") {
                        return message.channel.send("Checking if you have access to TRO.")
                        if (isTRO = 'true') {
                            message.reply('You have access to TRO.')
                        }
                    }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I have tried multiple solutions

I am trying to check for a specific role in a guild
and give a role on the "Current" guild.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`message.member.roles.cache.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) method to check if they have a role.

```js
message.member.roles.cache.has('948567643194003476');
```

Comment: Can you show some kind of example, I tried message.member.roles.cache.has() but it did not work.

Comment: I added an example ✅